# How to make Google Chrome stop asking to be the default browser?

Tags: google-chrome, web-browser

I installed Google Chrome on my MacBook for local development and testing. When I start it, it will nag about making it the default browser once in every while.

How can I stop it nagging me about that?

Answer (score 2):

This answer was tested on Windows/Chromium.

Decline the request, quit Chrome, edit the file `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences` and replace

`"default_browser_infobar_last_declined":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"` with `"default_browser_infobar_last_declined":"90000000000000000"`

Comment: If this was "tested on Windows/Chromium", how will this work on a Mac? Also, I was unable to find `"default_browser_infobar_last_declined"` in my Preferences file.

Comment: Worked for me on Chrome / macOS Monterey. The full JSONPath of the property is `$.browser.default_browser_infobar_last_declined`, just after the `clear_data` object and before `has_seen_welcome_page`.

Comment: No longer works, sadly

Comment: `default_browser_infobar_last_declined` does not exist in my file

Answer (score 0):

Quit Chrome and edit the file `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Preferences` and replace

```
"browser":{
```

with

```
"browser":{"check_default_browser":false,
```

Now it should not ask for being the default browser, anymore.

It's a mystery why this cannot be disabled in the settings menu, at least I was not able to find a way to disable it otherwise.